# List consumed when calling statistics.mean()

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, statistics

I'm attempting to read in a line of integer values separated by spaces and then perform a few simple statistical calculations on them.

An example line of input looks like so:

```
64630 11735 14216
```

I decided to use the `statistics` module from the Python Standard Library documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

Here is it in action:

```
import sys
import statistics

values = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())

print(statistics.mean(values))
print(statistics.median(values))
print(statistics.mode(values))
```

Upon executing, I get the following output from `stderr`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(statistics.median(values))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/statistics.py", line 313, in median
    raise StatisticsError("no median for empty data")
statistics.StatisticsError: no median for empty data
```

And so it seems the first call to `statistics.mean()` is consuming all of the elements in the `values` list before the call to `statistics.median()` can use them. (I do see the output from the first `print` statement from `stdout`, so the call to `statistics.mean()` worked fine.)

The input handling doesn't seem to have any issues. I have the following code that works as expected:

```
import sys
import statistics

values = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())

for v in values:
    print(v)
```

Outputting the following from `stdout`:

```
64630
11735
14216
```

Nothing in the standard library documentation mentions these functions consuming the parameter passed in. Each of these standard functions should only return a value and not alter the list itself.

Is there something specific to Python where a list can only be read or iterated on once? Or is there possibly a quirk with both of the compilers I've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` produces an iterable, and iteration over that can only be done *once*. If you want to be able to re-use the result, produce a list first from the `map()` results first:

```
values = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
values = [int(i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().split()]
```

Demo, using `list(map(...))`:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> import statistics
>>> demo = StringIO('64630 11735 14216\n')
>>> values = list(map(int, demo.readline().split()))
>>> print(statistics.mean(values))
30193.666666666668
>>> print(statistics.median(values))
14216
>>> print(statistics.mode(values))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.6/statistics.py", line 507, in mode
    'no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table)
statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 3 equally common values
```

Your input of 3 *unique* values has no mode, hence the last exception.

Comment: `map()` does indeed return an iterator instead of the same type passed in as I assumed.

Thank you for your answer!